# ECDF Function seems to be broken in R

Tags: r, ecdf

[Code and Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdQQc.png)

I am working on a problem which requires I create an ECDF from data. All was working well, and then it seems that all of a sudden my ECDF function started returning nonsense. To prove this I wrote the following lines of code:

```
set.seed(19191)
x <- rnorm(50)
x; ecdf(x)
plot(ecdf(x))
```

when I run these lines, I get what seems to be nonsense, as shown in the image I attached. This example is from this link: https://statisticsglobe.com/empirical-cumulative-distribution-function-ecdf-r

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can't reproduce - works fine for me.  Can you try in a fresh session (no packages loaded, and no saved environment loaded).  If you still have an issue in a fresh instance, then also post your R version and platform into the question

Comment: any chance you accidentally assigned something to `ecdf`, overwriting `stats::ecdf()` function?  For example `ecdf<-function(x) rep(0,length(x))` overwrites the `stats::ecdf()` function, replacing it with a new function that returns a vector of zeros the same length as the input, `x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I ran the same code in R it worked, so I realized it was an issue with RStudio. After updating RStudio, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem too and in my case, the problem solved by cleaning the R work place by `rm(list = ls())`.